# Cannot Implement JQuery UI Slider in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

What does the error message below mean?

The goal is to implement a dual-range slider, in JavaScript, to allow the user to input a range of values.

There are a plethora of these available online, and many of them are appropriate.  The problem appears to have nothing to do with the code of any one slider.

Have been able to implement several decent versions on an offline website, but am encountering errors when attempting to take the working code and integrate it into a WordPress custom template.

The following line of code

```
  $('.cinder-range').html('<span class="range-value">' 
            + $('#slider-range').slider("values", 0).toString() 
                + '</span><span class="range-divider"></span><span class="range-value">' 
                    + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1).toString() + '</span>');
```

triggers the following error:

***Uncaught Error: Method values does not exist on jQuery.tooltip***

The exact same error is triggered by several different implementations of the slider, when referencing the "values" field of the slider object.

This code for each of the attempted slider implementations work just fine by themselves.

What could be causing this error to be triggered, now that the code is on a WordPress page?

Have been sweating this problem for several days.  Finally done enough trial and error to be able to ask a cogent question. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: A difference between environments is usually caused by references which have been missed, or are pointing to difference versions of the libraries. Unfortunately, there's not enough information about  your code in the question to help you debug the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  What sources of information could be pursued to help figure this out?  How to track it down?

Comment: Manually compare the references in the output of both environments. Shouldn't take long to find a discrepancy

Comment: Both versions are using jquery 3.6.0 and jquery-ui 1.13.2.  What the heck does "Method 'x' does not exist in jQuery.tooltip mean?

Comment: I mean check *all* references, even your own code, not just jquery.

Comment: Please forgive.  not sure what you mean by "references" in this context.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Anywhere you use a `<script>` tag or `import` statement